# Idiomatic way to overcome difficulties with `@extension = 'html'` in AEM 6.3 Sightly/HTL?

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

AEM's HTL (f.k.a. Sightly) has a special idiom for reformatting URL properties, e.g.

```
<a href="${properties.path @ extension = 'html'}">
```

The purpose of this idiom is two-fold

1. to append `.html` to internal links authored via a `pathbrowser` field
2. to apply resource mappings which have been configured to strip `/content/projectname`

Unfortunately this well-intentioned feature has several problems:

- It won't work with resource links, e.g. a PDF file in the DAM.
- It won't work with external links that don't end in `.html`.
- It escapes the "&" in URLs containing query string params, breaking the link.

My team is now tasked with fixing dozens of defects caused by over-use of this `extension = 'html'` trick, and we would like to fix them all consistently and quickly with a minimum risk of regressions.

Is there a quick fix, preferrably something that can be repeated via mindless search/replace of every occurrence of `extension = 'html'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a combination of uri context and adding .html extension to resource URLs from server side.

- It won't work with resource links, e.g. a PDF file in the DAM.

Use `@ context = 'uri'`, default context for `href` and `src` attributes and does not explicitly add `.html` extension.

*Input* -

`<a href="${'/content/dam/repl/en.pdf'}">Resource Link</a>` uses default uri context.

*Output* -

`<a href="/content/dam/repl/en.pdf">Resource Link</a>`

On any other html attribute, use an attribute context - `@ context='attribute'`

*Input* -

`<div data-link="${'/content/dam/repl/en.pdf' @ context='attribute'}"/>`

*Output* -

`<div data-link="/content/dam/repl/en.pdf"/>`

---

- It won't work with external links that don't end in .html.
- It escapes the "&" in URLs containing query string params, breaking the link.

Again use `@ context = 'uri'`, does not escape **&** in URLs, works fine with selectors and # params as well. Added advantage of XSS protection.

*Input* -

`<a href="${'http://www.reddit.com.selector1.selector2?a=1&b=2&c=3'}">URI context</a>`

*Output* -

`<a href="http://www.reddit.com.selector1.selector2?a=1&b=2&c=3">URI context</a>`

- To append .html to internal resource URLs

You cannot use @ extension and @ context together in the same element. 
You could append .html like this `<a href="${path}.html">Title</a>` or better way would be to address this at the sling model level, a util method like this maybe.

```
public static String getUrl(String link, String extension, ResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
        String updatedLink = "";
        if (link != null) {
            Resource pathResource = resourceResolver.getResource(link);
            // check if resource exists
            if (pathResource != null) {
                // append .html
                updatedLink = resourceResolver.map(link) + extension;
            }
        }
        return updatedLink;
    }
```

Side note: Avoid `@ context='unsafe'` for obvious reasons - completely disables xss protection.

Check [this](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/1.1/SPECIFICATION.md#12-available-expression-options) for the available context expression options.